# Align resized tabular and image vertically

Tags: tables, graphics, vertical-alignment, positioning

I'm using this code to put a large table next to a figure.

```
\begin{figure}%[t!]
\centering
\begin{minipage}[c]{0.95\textwidth}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\resizebox{0.45\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{c c c c c c}
 % ... all the lines and stuff
\end{tabular} } & \includegraphics[width=0.45\textwidth]{./image.pdf}\\
(a) & (b) \\
\end{tabular}
\end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

However the code results in the table and the figure not being aligned correctly, as you can see below:

[image]

What is the problem?

Comment: Use 2 `minipage`s with the option `[c]` and appropriate widths and get rid of the outer `tabular`. But resizing like this, especially the table, is a really bad idea in terms of readability! You might like the `subcaption` or `floatrow` packages or something like that to help with creating sub-figures, though.

Comment: For your inner-`tabular`, use `\begin{tabular}[b]`...

Comment: @Werner - could you please explain why does that work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `tabular` and image has roughly the same height, then align them at their baselines. By default, `\includegraphics` is aligned at the base, but `tabular` is aligned at the vertical centre. Using `\begin{tabular}[b]` would suffice as it changes the vertical centre alignment to be aligned with the last line's baseline...

Other options include adding

```
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
```

to your preamble and using

```
\includegraphics[valign=c,...]{<image>}
```

This would align the image to the `tabular`s (default) vertical centre.